# Dúvida com comando sql em c#

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlCommand comm =
new SqlCommand("UPDATE Contatos Set Telefone=" + " ' " + txtTelefone.Text + " ' " + ",Cidade=" + " ' " + txtCidade.Text + " ' " + ",Email=" + " ' " + txtEmail.Text + " ' " + ",Endereco=" + " ' " + txtEndereco.Text + " ' " + "WHERE Nome=" + txtNome.Text, conn);
```

Erro: "Nome de coluna 'o nome que está no txtNome' inválido".
A mensagem de erro mostra como se eu tivesse tentando buscar o nome de uma coluna, onde o nome da coluna é txtNome.Text.
Minha intenção era que o comando sql atualizasse as informações do contato de acordo com seu nome.Tenho pouca experiência com sql e não consigo ver onde está meu erro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta é a maneira ruim de disparar um comando SQL. O correto é criar parâmetros para cada campo que será atualizado:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Contatos Set Telefone = @Telefone, " +
                                 "Cidade = @Cidade, " +
                                 "Email = @Email, " +
                                 "Endereco = @Endereco " +
                                 "WHERE Nome = @Nome", conn);

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txtTelefone.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cidade", txtCidade.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Endereco", txtEndereco.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txtNome.Text);
```

Comment: Verdade, vou testar assim. Fica até melhor de entender.

Answer (score 3):

Na clausula where faltou concatenar com aspas simples. Segue exemplo abaixo.

Mas seria melhor vc seguir o conselho que o Cigano Morrison Mendez passou.

```
"WHERE Nome=" + "'" + txtNome.Text + "'", conn);
```

Comment: O problema dessa abordagem é o risco de *SQL Injection*.

Comment: De que maneira acontece este SQL Injection?

Comment: Bruno Brito leia esse link, é de fácil compreensão sobre SQL Injection. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL